# I want to install react router dom using "npm install react-router-dom" but I am getting the errors which i don't know how to solve.?

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, peer

```
PS C:\ReactP\sample> npm install react-router-dom
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.10.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.3
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.10.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.10.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.10.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.10.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.10.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.10.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.10.3" from @mui/system@5.10.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.10.3" from @mui/material@5.10.3
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   14 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Ankit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ankit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-16T07_10_31_536Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\ReactP\sample>
```

I tried installation using --save, --force but failed to install

Answer (score 2):

Try to install it as:

```bash
npm i react-router-dom --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command for v6

```bash
npm i react-router-dom --force
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix this kind of problems
1.got to c:user\gideon\appdata\roaming
select two folder like npm and npm cache
delete it.some times it was hided have to unhide first and then get appadata folder as visible and then do next step as i did.
2. go to visual studio terminal.
3.npm i react-router-dom (paste this to install).
4.Press Enter to Install.

Comment: please improve the formatting of your answer to make it more readable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).